# C++/OpenGL Texture appearing Pixelated

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, textures

Here is my code for generating the texture(MRE):

```
    glGenTextures(1, &id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

    if(readAlpha)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    else
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Here is how Tex Coords are generated:

```
for (int y = 0; y < resolution; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < resolution; x++)
    {
        int i = x + y * resolution;
        glm::vec2 percent = glm::vec2(x, y) / ((float)resolution - 1);
        glm::vec3 pointOnPlane = (percent.x - .5f) * 2 * right + (percent.y - .5f) * 2 * front;
        pointOnPlane *= scale;
        vertices[i] = Vert();
        vertices[i].position = glm::vec3(0.0f);

        vertices[i].position.x = (float)pointOnPlane.x;
        vertices[i].position.y = (float)pointOnPlane.y;
        vertices[i].position.z = (float)pointOnPlane.z;
        vertices[i].texCoord = glm::vec2(percent.x, percent.y)*textureScale;
        vertices[i].normal = glm::vec3(0.0f);
        if (x != resolution - 1 && y != resolution - 1)
        {
            inds[triIndex] = i;
            inds[triIndex + 1] = i + resolution + 1;
            inds[triIndex + 2] = i + resolution;

            inds[triIndex + 3] = i;
            inds[triIndex + 4] = i + 1;
            inds[triIndex + 5] = i + resolution + 1;
            triIndex += 6;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the shader:
VERT:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNorm;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;
uniform mat4 _PV;
uniform mat4 _Model;
out DATA
{
    vec3 FragPos;
    vec3 Normal;
    vec2 TexCoord;
    mat4 PV;
} data_out; 
void main()
{
    gl_Position =  vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);
    data_out.FragPos = aPos;
    data_out.Normal = aNorm;
    data_out.TexCoord = aTexCoord;
    data_out.PV = _PV;
}
```

GEOM:

```
#version 330 core
layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;
out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec2 TexCoord;
in DATA
{
    vec3 FragPos;
    vec3 Normal;
    vec2 TexCoord;
    mat4 PV;
} data_in[]; 
void main()
{   
    gl_Position = data_in[0].PV * gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    Normal = data_in[0].Normal;
    TexCoord = data_in[0].TexCoord;
    FragPos = data_in[0].FragPos;
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = data_in[0].PV * gl_in[1].gl_Position;
    Normal = data_in[1].Normal;
    TexCoord = data_in[0].TexCoord;
    FragPos = data_in[1].FragPos;
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position =  data_in[0].PV * gl_in[2].gl_Position;
    Normal = data_in[2].Normal;
    TexCoord = data_in[0].TexCoord;
    FragPos = data_in[2].FragPos;
    EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

FRAG:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

uniform vec3 _LightPosition;
uniform vec3 _LightColor;

uniform sampler2D _Diffuse;
//unifrom float _UseTexutres;

in vec3 FragPos;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{   
    //vec3 objectColor = vec3(0.34f, 0.49f, 0.27f);
    vec3 objectColor = vec3(1, 1, 1);
    objectColor = texture(_Diffuse, TexCoord).xyz;
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(_LightPosition - FragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0f);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * _LightColor;
    vec3 result = (vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2) + diffuse) * objectColor;
    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
```

I am getting pixilated texture even thought I am using a 8K texture.

If you want to see the entire source : https://github.com/Jaysmito101/TerraGen3D

Here is the result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Frank i fixed the issue you are talking about but still it is the same pixelated image

Comment: The error you had would cause exactly the visual artifact you are describing. I'm really confident that was the issue. Either you have the same code elsewhere, or you need to do a clean build.

Comment: @Frank I did a clean build and i have updated the code still the issue is there. is there any other problem that might cause this kind of artifacts?

Comment: Well, that screenshot clearly exhibits GL_NEAREST filtering, so *something* is setting that on the texture.

Comment: @Frank all my texture related opengl code is from a file and i am never using NEAREST on purpose

Comment: `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` is not valid enum for `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` (see [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml)). Apart from that it makes no sense to set `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` and `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` twice.

Comment: @derhass i updated to add the details pls check once again

Comment: @Rabbid76 i tried removing them altogether still same

Comment: @derhass is anything more required for the MRE

Comment: Nope. There are lots of possibilities. And without reading all of the code, nobody can guess which parts of the code are not relevant. Definitively missing is the vertex shader, the whole attribute setup code, and also, which values do `resolution` and `textureScale` actually have in the example?

Comment: And, after having a brief look at the github repo, are you absolutely sure that `Texture2D::Resize` isn't called on your texture?

Comment: @derhass  i never call resize on this texture. Just  `diffuse = new Texture2D(path);`

Comment: @derhass i guess this has something to do with the geom shader not interpolating the data

Comment: Well, if there is a geometry shader involved, you should post it in the question. As I said, it is impossible to just guess.

Comment: @derhass added the geometry shader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your geometry shader does not make sense:

First of all, you use the same `data_in.TexCoords[0]` for all 3 vertices of of the output triangle, which means that all fragments generated for this triangle will sample the exact same location of the texture, resulting in the exact same output color, so the "pixelated" structure of the image emerges. Like you do already for `Normal` and `FragPos`, you should forward the data for each vertex. This already should solve your issue.

However, there are more issues with your approach. You do forward `mat4 PV` as per-Vertex data from the VS to the GS. However, the data you forward is an `uniform`, so this is a waste of resources. Every shader stage has access to all of the uniforms, so there is no need to forward this data per vertex.

But the real elephant in the room is what this geometry shader is supposed to be doing. The actual transformation with the uniform matrices can - and absolutely should - be carried out directly in the vertex shader. And the rest of your geometry shader is basically an attempt at a pass-through implementation (just a faulty one). So what do you need this shader for? You
can do the transformation in the VS and completely remove the geometry shader. And performance-wise, this will also be a win as geometry shaders are rather inefficent and should be avoided if not absolutely needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot this fixes my problems. And i know that the geometry shader does nothing and removing it is better but i want it to be there so that  users of the application can edit the geom shader from the in app shader editor. And yeah i will not pass the _PV from vert to geom.